# Laravel Rules Validation two Variables

Tags: laravel, validation, rules

I want to validate if a user(member) is part of a group via Validation Rules.
This is a part of my function...

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'idgroup' => [
                'required', 'numeric', new AdminGroupRequest
            ],
        'member' => [
                'required', 'numeric', new UserPartOfGroup
            ],
        ]);
```

And this is the Rules Class where I want to check if User is part of group.

```
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $userofgroup = Member::where([['groupid', /*Here I need idgroup*/], ['member', $value/*This is already member*/]])->select('id')->first();
    if($userofgroup){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use the [request()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-request) helpers:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return Member::where('groupid', request('idgroup'))
        ->where('member', $value)
        ->exists();
}
```

Or you could just use a [closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures) inside your `FormRequest`:

```
'member' => [
    'required', 'numeric', function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        $exists =  Member::where('groupid', $this->input('idgroup'))
            ->where('member', $value)
            ->exists();

        if (!$exists) {
            return $fail('Your error message goes here.');
        }
    }
],
```